# Can't get glob to find all files not starting with ~

Tags: php, arrays, glob

I have writen the following function to recursively find all files not starting with ~.  But it doesn't work.  In fact it only seems to find those that do start with ~

```
function rfl($dir) {
    $search=$dir."[^~]*";
    echo "searching for: $search<br/>";
    $search=glob($search);  //find every file and directory not starting with ~.  directories are returned with / afterwards
    $list=array();
    foreach ($search as $file) {
        if (is_dir($file)) {
            $list=array_merge($list,rfl($file.'/'));    //recursively search for valid files in directories
            echo 'D: ' . $file.'<br/>';
        } else {
            $list[]=$file;                          //add files to list
            echo 'F: ' . $file.'<br/>';
        }
    }
    return $list;
}
print_r(rfl('code/'));
```

returns

```
searching for: code/[^~]*
searching for: code/~private/[^~]*
D: code/~private
Array ( )
```

Here is the fixed function using Clayton's answer:

```
function rfl($dir) {
    $search = preg_grep('!^'.$dir.'[^~]!', glob($dir.'*')); //find every file and directory not starting with ~.  directories are returned with / afterwards
    $list=array();
    foreach ($search as $file) {
        if (is_dir($file)) {
            $list=array_merge($list,rfl($file.'/'));    //recursively search for valid files in directories
        } else {
            $list[]=$file;                          //add files to list
        }
    }
    return $list;
}
```

Comment: yes I do know how to accept answers.  Thank you for your help.  I edited my question to show the fixed function in case anyone needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glob` does not seem to really allow negation despite what one of the comments says on PHP's glob documentation.

Instead I suggest the following as an alternative:

```
$path = '../Sites/';
$results = preg_grep('!^'.preg_quote($path).'[^~]!', glob($path.'*'));
print_r($results);
```

preg_grep will filter the array to only allow results that do not begin with a tilde.  Since glob returns a full path, we need to escape and include the path in the regex pattern.

Read more here: http://php.net/preg_grep

> preg_grep — Return array entries that match the pattern
>
> **Usage**: *array preg_grep ( string $pattern , array $input [, int $flags = 0 ] )*

Here is your code updated to include the change:

```
function rfl($dir) {
    $search=$dir."[^~]*";
    echo "searching for: $search<br/>";

    $search= preg_grep('!^'.preg_quote($dir).'[^~]!', glob($dir.'*')); //find every file and directory not starting with ~.  directories are returned with / afterwards
    $list=array();
    foreach ($search as $file) {
        if (is_dir($file)) {
            $list=array_merge($list,rfl($file.'/'));    //recursively search for valid files in directories
            echo 'D: ' . $file.'<br/>';
        } else {
            $list[]=$file;                          //add files to list
            echo 'F: ' . $file.'<br/>';
        }
    }
    return $list;
}
print_r(rfl('code/'));
```

Answer (score 0):

all files not starting with ~:

```
$files = glob('./files/[!~]*.*');
```

jpg and png, not starting with ~:

```
$files = glob('./files/[!~]*.{jpg,png}', GLOB_BRACE);
```

you will find a detailed explanation here
https://cowburn.info/2010/04/30/glob-patterns/